# R transforming multi-class classification problem

Tags: r, transformation, multiclass-classification

Consider a dataset with features X1,X2 and response variable Y which has 8 classes namely 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. How can I use R to convert these 8 class problem into four class problem s.t when

```
Y=1 or 2, class =I
Y=3 or 4, class =II
Y=5 or 6, class =III
Y=7 or 8, class =Iv
```

or similarly 32 class problem 8 class problem or 16 class problem.
Is it something related to mapping function in R?

Currently what I am doing is, checking each class value if it is 1, I change it to I if it is 2 , I change it to I again?

Any simpler approach ? or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `ceiling` of `Y/2`. If you like, you can convert to Roman numerals using `as.roman`

```r
Y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

as.roman(ceiling(Y/2))
#> [1] I   I   II  II  III III IV  IV
```